# How to use conditional mock in Mockito

Tags: scala, mockito, wildcard, scalatest

I have a scala method call mocked in with mockito.

Let the object be `a` and method be `b` and the method b takes parameter of type `Map[String, String]`. I want to have a Map which meets a certain condition. I dont know all the key value pairs of this Map but I want to ensure that the Map has key value pairs like `key1` -> `value1` and `key2` -> `value2`
when I use something like this

`when(a.b(any[Map[String, String]])) thenReturn something`

Here `any` is a static member in `org.mockito`. But I cant use this in here as this mock is satisfied for `Map` with any key and value.
How to achieve a conditional mock in this case ??

I am looking for a utility which is analogous to `where` method which is in 
`org.scalamock.matchers.Matchers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `answers` from [`IdiomaticMockito`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#idiomatic-mockito) like so

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.mockito.{ArgumentMatchersSugar, IdiomaticMockito}

trait Foo {
  def bar(m: Map[String, String]): String
}

class FooSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with IdiomaticMockito with ArgumentMatchersSugar {
  "Foo object" should "say woohoo" in {
    val foo = mock[Foo]
    foo.bar(*) answers ((m: Map[String, String]) => if (m.exists(_ == ("key1", "value1"))) "woohoo" else "boom")
    foo.bar(Map("key1" -> "value1")) should be ("woohoo")
  }
}
```

Here we pass a conditional response to `answers` like so

```
if (m.exists(_ == ("key1", "value1"))) "woohoo" else "boom")
```

Note we use [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala) which is vanilla Mockito in addition to being aware of Scala specifics:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" %% "mockito-scala" % "1.5.11"
```

Here is the same solution with vanilla Mockito

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers._

trait Foo {
  def bar(m: Map[String, String]): String
}

class FooSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "Foo object" should "say woohoo old syntax" in {
    val foo = Mockito.mock(classOf[Foo])
    doAnswer({ args =>
      val m = args.getArgument[Map[String, String]](0)
      if (m.exists(_ == ("key1", "value1"))) "woohoo" else "boom"
    }).when(foo).bar(any[Map[String, String]])

    foo.bar(Map("key1" -> "value1")) should be ("woohoo")
  }
}
```